# how to debug a dll winamp plugin in Visual Studio 2010 written in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, winamp

I'm developing a Winamp plugin. I have a project that builds a `.dll` file. This file is actually the plugin. I want to debug that plugin.
I need some recipe Step by step. I have already set the `Configuration Properties - > Debug ging -> Command` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe"`. So, when I hit debug winamp actually starts the plugin but then some C++ runtime fatal error occure.

---

EDIT:

The question is how to prepare for the debugging? How to tell winamp.exe that gen_my_file.dll is a plug-in? (Winamp scans the `C:/Program Files/Winamp/Plugins/` directory for plugins. To start the plugin It must be there, but how to tell visual studio export the .dll there and link it somehow?)

Here is what is happening:
1) I hit F5

[image]

Then I hit YES.

2) Second message appears

[image]

3) Voila the plugin is started!

[image]

4) ... and when I hit OK ...

[image]

I have tested this with **empty project** so, there is no way to breaks because of bug in the plug-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a few days of research, finally I found a solution!
The problem with the errors was resolved, they was my problem. 
The most important part is that I had to set post-build event that copies the dll to the appropiate directory (../Winamp/Plugins). After this intervention the debuging was working like a charm :) Here is an example with Paint.NET - it work at the same principle.
http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/4209-how-to-debug-your-plugin/